# java list generator of all possible combinations

Tags: java

I want to make a function that will make a list of all possible combinations of a charset between length n and n+m in java.
I'm trying to demonstrate how hash cracking works and I was asked to write in java, but I'm not very familiar with it.
I would also like to know if there is something like the python yeald function in java and if so how can I imlement it.

Comment: I didn’t know `yield` in Python before (I assume this is what you mean). If I have understood it correctly, I should say a stream in Java are like the generator you get from `yield`. PS I didn’t understand the part about the charset between n and n+m. And certainly writing a generator doesn’t require a stream, this one out of more options.

Comment: I don't have anything that works yet I was hoping to get some help, a place to start from because I don't understand how is it possible to make a function that can generate all possible combinations of a charset of what ever length I input it. I know how to do it with nested for loops but I need a for loop for every place (for length n I need n loops).

Comment: @AgataB, I’m sure you meant “We *don’t* write code for you …”

Comment: Lendion, you’re in the wrong place at this time. First use your favourite search engine to find what has already been written about generating combinations in Java, I assure you it’s a lot, more than enough to get you started writing some code. If you get stuck at a point or your code misbehaves, we’ll be here to help, promise.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes. That. Apologies for the oversight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try if this sample can help you. It takes 3 variables: The charset, the max and the min length and lists all combinations.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public abstract class Main {
    int max = 4;
    int min = 2;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Main() {
            public void element(char[] result, int offset, int length) {
                System.out.println(new String(result, offset, length));
            }
        }.generate("ABCD");
    }

    private void generate(char[] input) {
        char[] result = new char[input.length];
        int[] index = new int[input.length];

        // initialize the arrays.
        Arrays.fill(result, 0, result.length, input[0]);
        Arrays.fill(index, 0, index.length, 0);

        // loop over the output lengths.

        for (int length = min; length <= max; length++) {
            int updateIndex = 0;
            do {
                element(result, 0, length);

                // update values that need to reset.
                for (updateIndex = length - 1;
                     updateIndex != -1 && ++index[updateIndex] == input.length;
                     result[updateIndex] = input[0], index[updateIndex] = 0, updateIndex--)
                    ;

                // update the character that is not resetting, if valid
                if (updateIndex != -1) result[updateIndex] = input[index[updateIndex]];
            }
            while (updateIndex != -1);
        }
    }

    void generate(String input) {
        generate(input.toCharArray());
    }

    public abstract void element(char[] result, int offset, int length);
}
```

Test

```
AA
AB
AC
AD
BA
BB
BC
BD
CA
CB
CC
CD
DA
DB
DC
DD
AAA
AAB
AAC
AAD
ABA
ABB
ABC
ABD
ACA
ACB
ACC
ACD
ADA
ADB
ADC
ADD
BAA
BAB
BAC
BAD
BBA
BBB
BBC
BBD
BCA
BCB
BCC
BCD
BDA
BDB
BDC
BDD
CAA
CAB
CAC
CAD
CBA
CBB
CBC
CBD
CCA
CCB
CCC
CCD
CDA
CDB
CDC
CDD
DAA
DAB
DAC
DAD
DBA
DBB
DBC
DBD
DCA
DCB
DCC
DCD
DDA
DDB
DDC
DDD
AAAA
AAAB
AAAC
AAAD
AABA
AABB
AABC
AABD
AACA
AACB
AACC
AACD...
```

You can try it [online](http://ideone.com/IW7fXa).

Comment: That obviously works. Pesonally I find the code complicated and hard to read and follow. If you’re comfortable with recursion, that’s what I’d use instead.